# Classifying twists for a general moduli problem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-stacks

Suppose $\mathfrak X$ is a (Deligne-Mumford/Artin/...) stack and denote by $|\mathfrak X(k)|$ the set of isomorphism classes of it's $k$-valued point. Can we say something in general about the fibers of the map $|\mathfrak X(k)| \to |\mathfrak X(\overline{k}|$?

In special examples, this is usually some cohomology class. For instance, if $\mathscr X = \mathcal M_{1,1}$, then the twists of an elliptic curve are classified by $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q})/\mathbb Q),\mathrm{Aut}_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}(E))$.

On the other hand, for a "nice" algebraic group acting on a variety $V$, the $G(\mathbb Q)$ orbits that coalesce to a $G(\overline{\mathbb Q})$ orbit are classified by the kernel of the map $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q})/\mathbb Q), \mathrm{Stab}_v(\overline{\mathbb Q})) \to H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q})/\mathbb Q),G(\overline{\mathbb Q}))$. I think in many cases, this corresponds to $\mathfrak X = V/G$.

In any given example, I find that I can prove a similar statement by some explicit calculation. Is there a unified explanation of this phenomena?

Comment: Might the proof of Prop 4.19 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09876.pdf  be useful?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks that's very useful. I guess I am interested in when exactly we can say which subgroup of $H^1(A,I_x)$ the twists are (in the notation of the paper).